# How to set an emit style for a particular yaml-cpp node

Tags: yaml-cpp

I'm emitting a YAML document as follows:

```
YAML::Node doc; // ...populate doc...
YAML::Emitter out;
out << doc;
```

Somewhere in the hierarchy of nodes I have a particular sequence that I would like to emit in the `Flow` style while everything else should use the default style settings.

I can't seem to find any way of doing this other than emitting by hand every node and watching out for the nodes I'm interested in.  This seems like a high price to pay for something relatively straightforward.

Ideally I'd like to be able to tag the `Node` to say "If you get emitted, do so with the following style".  But I don't think there's any support for this.

Can anyone think of a way around having to emit the whole document by hand?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has already been implemented as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659434/how-to-set-yaml-cpp-node-style).

You can set the node style with the following code

```
node.SetStyle(YAML::EmitterStyle::Flow);
```

or

```
node.SetStyle(YAML::EmitterStyle::Block);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not possible, but I've submitted it as a feature request:

http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=184

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  I'll probably implement something along the lines of what you've suggested in the feature request.  More than happy to share the path when I'm done if you're interested.