# how to set yaml-cpp node style?

Tags: yaml-cpp

I have a vector3 class.

```
class vector3
{
    float x, y, z;
}

node["x"] = vector3.x;
node["y"] = vector3.y;
node["z"] = vector3.z;
```

The result is

```
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0
```

I want the result to be:

```
{x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
```

If use the old API, I can use `YAML::Flow` to set the style:

```
YAML::Emitter emitter;
out << YAML::Flow  << YAML::BeginMap << YAML::Key << "x" << YAML::Value << x << YAML::EndMap
```

Using the new API, how can I set the style?

I asked this question on a yaml-cpp project issue page:

https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=186

I got the answer:

> You can still use the emitter and set the flow style:
>
> ```
> YAML::Emitter emitter;
> emitter << YAML::Flow << node;
> ```

but the `vector3` is part of the object. I specialize the `YAML::convert<>` template class

```
template<>
struct convert<vector3>
{
    static Node encode(const vector3 & rhs)
    {
        Node node = YAML::Load("{}");
        node["x"] = rhs.x;
        node["y"] = rhs.y;
        node["z"] = rhs.z;

        return node;
    }
}
```

so I need to return a node, but the emitter can't convert to a node.

I need the object to like that:

```
GameObject:
  m_Layer: 0
  m_Pos: {x: 0.500000, y: 0.500000, z: 0.500000}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you copy your code for emitting the entire YAML? Is your entire YAML document a single Node, or do you want to output it piecemeal?

Comment: Also, can you clarify what "but the `vector3` is part of the object` means?

Comment: sorry, i mean that object has a member variable which type is vector3.

Comment: i find a thread in stackoverflow, also ask the same question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282645/how-to-set-an-emit-style-for-a-particular-yaml-cpp-node?rq=1. when does this feature will be implement?

Answer (score 1):

A while ago the node interface was extended in yaml-cpp to include a `SetStyle()` function adding the following line anywhere in `encode` should have the desired result

```
node.SetStyle(YAML::EmitterStyle::Flow);
```